# navigate after code on button click

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am a bit of an armature and wondering how I can navigate to a different page after some code has been executed on a button click? Here is what I have

```
  private void saveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            address = bitCoinAddress.Text;
            // create directory called locationData
            myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("Contact");
            // create file called location.txt inside locationData directory
            writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Contact\\me.txt", FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage));
            writeFile.WriteLine(address);
            writeFile.Close();
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Contacts.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        catch (Exception b)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("error saving Bitcoin address");
            Console.WriteLine("An error occured:" + b);
        }
```

Comment: What problem are you seeing?

Comment: For some reason it was getting an exception on the navigation service but once i moved it to outside of the try/catch it worked, hmm weird

Comment: Probably because an exception occured before the NavigationService line, and it never executed. By moving it outside of the try {} block, you'll get the navigation to happen, but you will still have the exception happening when writing to the file.

Comment: when exception occur inside try block, application will jump to catch block right after line of code that caused the exception. Hence if that happened in your case, `NavigationService.Navigate(...);` won't get executed.

Comment: Can you paste the exception details in too?

Answer (score 1):

Most definitely, the problem is in this line:

```
myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("Contact");
```

Because in the button_click event you can't guarantee, that myIsolatedStorage object is still alive (it may already be disposed, code should be wrapped into *using* to prevent that). Rewrite you code in this style:

```
using (myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (!myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists("Contact"))
                        myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("Contact");

                    using (writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Contact\\me.txt", FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage)))
                    {
                      writeFile.WriteLine(address);
                    }
                }
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Contacts.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

This code works fine for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Using also doesn't guarantee permision - thought it is nice, because myIsolatedStorage will be disposed. The problem was probably that directory already exists when tried to create new.

Comment: Yeah, no "permission" problems, I meant object living time, of course. Btw, if the directory already exists, the .CreateDirectory method will do nothing according to msdn, and no exception will be thrown.

Comment: You are right with creating directory. And your code with using is much better than OP's (+1).